# Auth0/Android Custom Scope

Tags: android, authentication, auth0

I am trying to logged with auth0 in android I am setting a custom scope for some extra value like userId in IdToken I getting this value on postman. But in android auth0 does not return userId in token. setScope does not work. I would be appreciate any help.

```
private AuthSessionManager(){
    storage = new SharedPreferencesStorage(ContextProvider.get());
    auth0 = new Auth0(getAuth0ClientId(),getAuth0Domain());
    auth0.setLoggingEnabled(true);
    auth0.setOIDCConformant(true);
    authApiCli = new AuthenticationAPIClient(auth0);
}

public Credentials loginWithEmailAndPassword(String email, String password){
    Log.i(TAG, "loginWithEmailAndPassword: Scope: "+getAUTH0SCOPE());
    Log.i(TAG, "loginWithEmailAndPassword: Device: "+getAUTH0DEVICE());
    return authApiCli.login(email,password,getAuth0Connection())
            .setScope(getAUTH0SCOPE())
            .setDevice(getAUTH0DEVICE())
            .execute();
}
```

IdToken:

```
...
  "first_login": false,
  "email_verified": true,
  "user_id": "userid", // does not return in android
...
```

Comment: what's the scope you are setting? `getAUTH0SCOPE` value? when you don't set the scope do you get the `user_id`?

Comment: i solved the problem. it was my mistake i was act like blind because i focus to much.OIDCconformant must be false when setting scope. (:

Comment: okay glad you solved it! Feel free to answer your SO question with the solution and mark it as solved in cause others make a similar issue/mistake. Also, if you ever have these type of Auth0 specific questions checkout https://community.auth0.com/ you may have better luck with getting help to your questions, plus you can find helpful posts from other users. Cheers!